# Как сохранить данные в кодировке utf-16-le?

Tags: python

Хочу сохранить содержимое csv-файла в кодировке `utf-16-le`
Вот мой код

```
with open(subfolder+'.csv', mode='a',newline='') as employee_file:
    writer = csv.writer(employee_file,delimiter=";")
    row = ['    '+'Job1'+'  '+'     '+'M']
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Вот то что нашёл в инете

```
import codecs

mytext = "Help me"

with open("c:\\temp\\myFile.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE)
    f.write(mytext.encode('utf-16-le')
```

Основная проблема что у меня идёт работа с csv. Непонятно как задать кодировку? И как занести список в строку

Comment: А так `with open(subfolder+'.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-16-le', newline='') as employee_file:`?

Comment: А как быть с writerow?

Comment: @Radzhab, а что writerow? Он скорее всего внутри использует метод write файла, а метод write уже сам знает как писать в файл в правильной кодировке.

Comment: @Radzhab, кстати пример который вы нашли - либо неправильный, либо для Python2, потому что файл открывается как текстовый, а запись идет как в бинарный.

Comment: @insolor а как быть:?

Comment: @insolor оно так не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий пример:

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv', mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-16-le') as employee_file:
    writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=";")
    row = ['Job1', 'M']
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Содержимое файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываем полученный файл через LibreOffice, формат автоматом определяется:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: спасибо за ответ) подскажите плиз а как сделать utf-16-le with bom?

Comment: Чисто технически можно записать `employee_file.write('\ufeff')` в начале файла.

Comment: такой вариант не подходит(((